# How to join pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables like this to show all the categories that each story in it. How to make it show all category use join 3 tables. Should i use join or query in view/blade

[catogory model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG92Q.png)

[story model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2LPi.png)

[view/blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fovsC.png)

[structure category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Q1V.png)

[structure story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Uqz.png)

[structure pivot tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc5AT.png)

Comment: A best practice in Laravel if to use relationships, please refer to the documentation. Also, your question is not answerable as written, if you want would like a better response, please provide more detail regarding your database structure and the related pivot tables that you need to join.

Comment: i added structure table

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the update, given the above, in your Controller I'm assuming you are calling something like `Story::all()`, you are going to want to eager load the categories with `$data = Story::with('categories')->get()`, then in your blade file you can loop through the categories and print out the name fields with

```
@foreach($data as $story)

    {{ $story->name }}

    @foreach($story->categories as $category)

        {{ $category->name }}

    @endforach

@endforeach
```

You can add any additional markup that you need.

Comment: in blade i get the error `Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance`

Comment: Story Controller `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoryRequest;
use App\Story;
use App\Category;

class StoryController extends Controller
{
    public function getList()
    {
        $data = Story::with('categories')->get();
        return view('admin.story.list', compact('data'));
    }`

Comment: Ok, so now in your view you should have something `@foreach($data as $story)` which builds your table rows, and inside of that loop place my solution. If you not using `$story` as the variable change it to what you are using in your view to the variable for each row data.

Comment: in blade i use `@foreach($data as $category)

                                {!! $category !!}

                            @endforeach` it show [link](https://anotepad.com/notes/5here6) and i use `@foreach($story->categories as $category)

    {{ $category->name }}

@endforach` it will be get error `Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance`

Comment: Well what you have is now is confusing you and you need to change it, because each if your `$data = Story::with('categories')->get() then how could `@foreach($data as $category)` make any sense? Your data items are not categories, they are stories. I edited my answer try that and you'll see what I mean. Personally, I don't use variables like $data because they don't mean anything, I would rename `$data` to `$stories` so you don't get confused what your working with regardless if you are in your controller or your view you know that $stories are stories.